# How to create and exception for a bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '!' in message.content:   
        return
    if message.content.startswith(muti):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await message.delete()
    else:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(muti)
    if message.author.bot:
        return
```

I am trying to create an exception where my bot will not delete another bot's message, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to use if message.author.(the other bot's id variable) but then I don't know how to set that variable up. The message.author.bot is for my bot to ignore its own messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `member.bot` which returns if the member is a bot [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.bot).

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if '!' in message.content:   
        return
    if message.content.startswith(muti):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await message.delete()
    else:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(muti)
    if message.author.bot:
        return
```

This will not execute any of the code below if the message was sent by a bot.